# OpenOffice ODM (OpenDocument Master Document) format

Tags: format, openoffice.org, sample, openoffice-writer

In development of a text editor application, I came across a need to test an .ODM format (OpenDocument Master Document) support. I tried searching OpenOffice documentation for samples, but failed to find any.

Please suggest where to find such samples.

Answer (score 2):

You can make them with OpenOffice.org Writer.

I did it once just to see how it worked.

OK, I am using the ODF 1.2 Specification Part 3 because it is not too large but has several chapters.

So I opened OpenDocument-v1.2-cs01-part3.odt  (actually using LibreOffice 3.3.2 but OpenOffice.org 3.3.0 and earlier work the same way).

On the menu bar select File | Send > Create Master Document

This will give you a Name and Path of Master Document dialog, with Save as type set to ODF Master Document (*.odm).

I navigated the Save dialog to the folder where I wanted to save the Master and its parts.  I then specified MasterDocDemo.  There's a Template setting pull-down which defaults to Outline Level 1. I left that alone and clicked "Save."  I ended up with an 8-part document:

```
 MasterDocDemo.odm
 MasterDocDemo1.odt
 MasterDocDemo2.odt
 ...
 MasterDocDemo7.odt
```

Do that yourself with something that has chapters or something with headings at Outline Level 1 and then explore.

Answer (score 0):

Opendocument format 1.1 specification on [schemacentral](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/odf/s-OpenDocument-schema-v1.1.xsd.html)

You can find all type of open document format specification provided by OASIS [here](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office). (including v1.1, v1.2)

LibreOffice and OOo supports this format. To create ODF master doc you can export odt files to odm from Lo or OOo.

Comment: I'm looking for an actual sample of the document, not specifications or schema.